# How to get ImageIcon path a String Java Jtable

Tags: java, swing, path, jtable, imageicon

```
if (j == model.getColumnCount() - 1) {
    JLabel excelJL = (JLabel) model.getValueAt(i, j);
    ImageIcon excelImageIcon = (ImageIcon) excelJL.getIcon();
    System.out.println(excelImageIcon.);
}
```

I have an image stored in `JLabel` and displayed in `JTable` row cell.

How can I get the image path as a string?

I am able to retrieve the image and display it on another label but I am stuck at getting its path.

```
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) You are overthinking this. Instead of the current method: 1) Don't put a `JLabel` into the table cell, instead put the image itself. 2) Tell that table column to expect an `Image`. It will automatically use an `ImageIcon` / `JLabel` to render it. 3) When you need the image, ask for the value of the appropriate table cell, then use the **image itself** for the other label.

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel excelJL = (JLabel) model.getValueAt(i, j);
ImageIcon excelImageIcon = (ImageIcon) excelJL.getIcon();

//Image Name Is Stored In ImageIcons Description First set it And Then Retrieve it
String excelImagePath = excelImageIcon.getDescription();
```

I managed to get image path using getDescription() method. But first you need to set the description when adding image to jtable cell.